# Identifying bifurcation

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stability, bifurcation

[![enter image description here]] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvXgU.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvXgU.jpg)I am trying to analyze the bifurcation of a 3D continuous model. For a certain range of parameter values, the origin is always an unstable point, whereas the symmetric equilibria shift their stability from asymptotically stable to unstable, and periodic orbits bifurcate around them while the complex conjugate eigenvalues cross the imaginary axis. I am guessing that it is a Hopf bifurcation or trans-critical bifurcation. Which one is correct?

Comment: Can you add a bifurcation diagram ?

Comment: I have added the bifurcation diagram by varying the parameter of interest from 6 to 7, since the phenomena I have observed occur in this range.